# iOS8 App with iAds: Can each view controller enable canDisplayBannerAds?

Tags: ios, iad, adbannerview

I am creating an iOS8+ application and am ready to add iAd to it.  At this time, I've set the following in viewDidLoad() for each UIViewController in my application:

self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

Everything seems to be working properly... Ads are appearing when I switch between views.  Is this the proper way to enable iAd with multiple views on iOS8 and newer releases?

I have not found any documentation that says how to use canDisplayBannerAds with multiple view controllers.  I found a lot of postings for earlier releases of iOS where the developer had to implement iAd on his/her own, and only create a singleton.  Anyway, I hope that someone can verify that what I have done is correct and will work properly when the app goes to the store.

Thank you for your time and help,

Mike

Comment: `Yes, this is perfectly fine even for iOS 7. The documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/canDisplayBannerAds).

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the quick response and verification! So, I will use this method rather than dealing with managing the banner myself. :)